# Microsoft.Ink RealTimeStylus doesn't work on some computers

Tags: microsoft.ink

We have an application that uses Microsoft.Ink as its RealTimeStylus to let our users draw annotations on images.
The problem that we have is that it's not working on some computers.It seems that some required files are missing but I couldn't find requirements list for this component on the Net.
The exception that we get is an InvalidOerationException and it's message is : Initialization has failed.

Comment: It seems that service pack 3 of windows XP should be installed